# buttonBar custom component

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, dataprovider

I am using a custom component at the top of my application that includes an image and a buttonBar. I have the namespace declared in main.mxml as comps and the package is components. When I assign the dataProvider to the buttonBar and run the application, all I get is a blank page. If I remove the dataProvider everything loads fine. the dataProvider is supposed to be the ViewStack component I have in the main.mxml. The buttonBar and image custom component is TopNav.mxml

The problem is that my TopNav component does not know the dataProvider I am asking it to change; MyViewStack. Do I need to create a public viewstack variable and pass it to the component?

Comment: can you share the problematic code here please?

Comment: Databinding is done at the source did you make it Bindable in the main.mxml

Comment: something like `<fx:Script [BINDABLE] public var myViewstack:new ViewStack; />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is probably throwing a runtime error.  Do you have Flash Player debug installed?  You can see it here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html

If your application has a runtime error, it won't continue executing code.  You probably have a null pointer somewhere.